# Web2py Drop down menu that filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web2py

New to *html/javascript/web2py*, but I been reading a lot and saw many different ways into sorting and some ways to filtering. However, I haven't found something that is similar to mine.
Right now, I'm creating a website that is similar to Craigslist where you can post items and I'm attempting to make a drop down menu that can filter. For an example, if I click car, it will only show posts that has the keyword Car in the category.

Right now, you can create a post and (IS_IN_SET) will already have the categories there for you. However, this is where I'm getting lost. I'm not sure how to get the keywords from (IS_IN_SET) so I am able to use those words to filter.

This is in db.py

```
db.define_table('posts',  
Field('title', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),  
Field('interests'),  
Field('category', requires=IS_IN_SET(['Computer', 'Electronics', 'Cars', 'Video Games'])),
```

In my default/index, I created

```
 <select>  
    <option value='0'>(Select Category)</option><!--added-->
    <option value="Computer">Computer</option>
    <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
    <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value="Video Games">Video Games</option>
    </select>
```

But I don't know where to go from here. 
I read that you can use IS_IN_DB to create a drop down filter list.
I tried using, but I'm pretty sure this is wrong....
    db.category.requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'category.id','%(Tcategory)s')

Looking for any advice/tips in trying to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that shows the power and simplicity of Web2py.  I also added a form to enter new posts.  Tested.

IN MODEL (models/posts.py):

```
post_categories = ['Computer', 'Electronics', 'Cars', 'Video Games']

db.define_table('posts',
    Field('title', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),  
    Field('interests'),  
    Field('category', requires=IS_IN_SET(post_categories)),
    Field('body', "text")
    )
```

IN VIEW (views/default/posts.html):

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}

<div>
 <select id="post-select">  
    <option value='0'>(Select Category)</option>

    {{for item in post_categories:}}

    <option value="{{=item}}">{{=item}}</option>

    {{pass}}

 </select>
</div>

{{=form}}

{{=LOAD('default','posts_load', vars=dict(category=item_selected), target='posts-ajax', ajax=True)}}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

    // pre-sets the option
    $('#post-select option[value="{{=item_selected}}"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    $('#post-select').change(function(event) {

        var itemSelected = $(this).val();

        var urlOfLoadedComponent = "{{=URL(c='default', f='posts_load')}}";

        /* either one of these works but the first is better because it uses ajax */

        // refreshes the component with the new subset of records
        web2py_component( urlOfLoadedComponent + '?category=' + itemSelected, target='posts-ajax');

        //window.location.replace('http:/localhost/posts?category=' + itemSelected);
    });
});
</script>
```

IN VIEW (views/default/posts_load.html):

```
{{for post in post_rows:}}
<div class="post">
  Title: <div class="post_title">{{=post.title}}</div>
  Post:  <blockquote class="post_body">{{=post.body}}</blockquote>
</div>
{{pass}}
```

IN CONTROLLER (controllers/default.py):

```
"""
Usage:

http:/localhost/default/posts
-- or --
http:/localhost/default/posts?category=Computer
"""
def posts():

    # if category is specified in the url vars, use it otherwise use 'Computer'
    item_selected = request.vars.get('category', 'Computer')

    # or you could use the first one in the list:
    #item_selected = request.vars.get('category', post_categories[0])

    """
    creates the form
    processes new posts; posts() function called again on form submit via ajax
    the response.js refreshes form after ajax post
    """
    form=SQLFORM(db.posts).process()
    response.js = "jQuery('#posts-ajax').get(0).reload();"

    """
    you don't need to pass "post_categories = post_categories" in the dict
    because the view can see the variables defined in the models it runs
    """
    return dict(
                form = form,
                item_selected = item_selected
                )

def posts_load():

    category = request.vars.get('category', '')

    if category:

        post_rows = db(db.posts.category==category).select()

    else:

        post_rows = db(db.posts).select()

    return post_rows
```

Comment: Right now, I'm trying to use a form tag style so that once you click on it, it will go to the view call "showByCategory" where it should filter it, but I'm not sure how to work that out. Also, I tried doing what you were using in your model post_categories = ['Computer', 'Electronics', 'Cars', 'Video Games'], however when I try using <select id="post_categories"> in my index, the values doesn't show up.

Comment: Sorry there were a few errors in my code.  All fixed and tested.  Let me know if you have any trouble.